# How do I debug jonesforth with GDB?

Tags: assembly, gdb, gnu-assembler, forth

jonesforth is typically started as follows:

```
cat jonesforth.f  - | ./jonesforth
```

What's a good way to debug `jonesforth`?

Answer (score 5):

## On Ubuntu?

If you're on Ubuntu, allow `gdb` to attach to running processes:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

If you'd like that setting to remain across reboots:

```
vim /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
```

## Update Makefile

Add the `g` flag to your `jonesforth` `Makefile` recipe:

```
jonesforth: jonesforth.S
    gcc -g -m32 -nostdlib -static $(BUILD_ID_NONE) -o $@ $<
```

## Starting gdb

Then, start up jonesforth as usual in a terminal:

```
cat jonesforth.f - | ./jonesforth
```

In another terminal, start `gdb` and attach it to the running jonesforth:

```
gdb --quiet --pid=`pgrep jonesforth`  ./jonesforth
```

## Sample session

Here's what I see when I start `gdb`:

```
$ gdb --quiet --pid=`pgrep jonesforth`  ./jonesforth 
Reading symbols from ./jonesforth...done.
Attaching to program: /home/dharmatech/Dropbox/Documents/jonesforth-annexia/jonesforth, process 3406
_KEY () at jonesforth.S:1290
1290        test %eax,%eax      // If %eax <= 0, then exit.
(gdb)
```

Jonesforth is waiting for us to enter something. It's in the `_KEY` assembly routine. This is indicated by `gdb` above. It also shows that line 1290 is the next one to execute. Here's the `_KEY` routine:

```
_KEY:
    mov (currkey),%ebx
    cmp (bufftop),%ebx
    jge 1f          // exhausted the input buffer?
    xor %eax,%eax
    mov (%ebx),%al      // get next key from input buffer
    inc %ebx
    mov %ebx,(currkey)  // increment currkey
    ret

1:  // Out of input; use read(2) to fetch more input from stdin.
    xor %ebx,%ebx       // 1st param: stdin
    mov $buffer,%ecx    // 2nd param: buffer
    mov %ecx,currkey
    mov $BUFFER_SIZE,%edx   // 3rd param: max length
    mov $__NR_read,%eax // syscall: read
    int $0x80
    test %eax,%eax      // If %eax <= 0, then exit.
    jbe 2f
    addl %eax,%ecx      // buffer+%eax = bufftop
    mov %ecx,bufftop
    jmp _KEY

2:  // Error or end of input: exit the program.
    xor %ebx,%ebx
    mov $__NR_exit,%eax // syscall: exit
    int $0x80
```

`_KEY` uses some variables in memory: `buffer`, `currkey`, and `bufftop`. It also uses a couple of registers. Let's use `gdb`'s `Auto Display` feature to display these:

```
display/8cb &buffer
display/1xw &currkey
display/1xw &bufftop
display/x   $eax
display/x   $ebx
```

Now if we type `display` in `gdb`, we'll see all of those at once:

```
(gdb) display
1: x/8cb &buffer
0x804c000:  97 'a'  98 'b'  108 'l' 121 'y' 46 '.'  32 ' '  32 ' '  84 'T'
2: x/xw &currkey  0x8049d54:    0x0804c000
3: x/xw &bufftop  0x8049d58:    0x0804c7e3
4: /x $eax = 0xfffffe00
5: /x $ebx = 0x0
```

This might also be a good time to enable `gdb`'s TUI:

```
tui enable
```

gdb should now look like this:

[image]

OK, jonesforth is still waiting for input. So let's give it  something:

```
JONESFORTH VERSION 47 
14499 CELLS REMAINING
OK 123
```

Alright, back in gdb, we can finally ask it to step:

```
(gdb) s
1: x/8cb &buffer
0x804c000:      49 '1'  50 '2'  51 '3'  10 '\n' 46 '.'  32 ' '  32 ' '  84 'T'
2: x/xw &currkey  0x8049d54:    0x0804c000
3: x/xw &bufftop  0x8049d58:    0x0804c7e3
4: /x $eax = 0x4
5: /x $ebx = 0x0
```

Hey, look at that! The first 3 characters in `buffer` are `1`, `2`, and `3`.

If `%eax <= 0` the next step will jump to the `2f` label. But as we can see above, `%eax` is `4`. So it should just continue on.

If we step through the next three lines, the `bufftop` will be set to the address of `buffer` incremented by 4 (three characters of '123' plus a newline character). The value in relation to the address of `buffer` checks out:

```
3: x/xw &bufftop  0x8049d58:    0x0804c004
```

Now that data has been read into the input buffer, `_KEY` will do its job and return back to the caller. Here's the next few instructions before the return:

[image]

As you step through those, the auto display feature will show the variables and registers updating accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My (quite limited!) experience is that the LLVM debugger lldb is much friendlier when tinkering with assembly-language programs.