# Displaying dictionary word with GDB in Jonesforth

Tags: gcc, assembly, gdb, gnu-assembler, forth

In [Jonesforth](https://github.com/nornagon/jonesforth/blob/master/jonesforth.S), a dictionary entry is laid out as follows:

```
<--- DICTIONARY ENTRY (HEADER) ----------------------->
+------------------------+--------+---------- - - - - +----------- - - - -
| LINK POINTER           | LENGTH/| NAME          | DEFINITION
|                        | FLAGS  |               |
+--- (4 bytes) ----------+- byte -+- n bytes  - - - - +----------- - - - -
```

We can take a peek at one of these entries using GDB. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628756/how-do-i-debug-jonesforth-with-gdb) for details on using GDB with Jonesforth.)

Let's display the first 16 bytes of the dictionary entry for `SWAP` as characters:

```
>>> x/16cb &name_SWAP
0x105cc:    -68 '\274'    5 '\005'    1 '\001'    0 '\000'    4 '\004'    83 'S'    87 'W'    65 'A'
0x105d4:    80 'P'    0 '\000'    0 '\000'    0 '\000'    43 '+'    0 '\000'    1 '\001'    0 '\000'
```

You can kind of see what's going on here.

The first four bytes are the pointer to the previous word in the dictionary:

```
-68 '\274'    5 '\005'    1 '\001'    0 '\000'
```

Then comes the length of the name:

```
4 '\004'
```

Then we see the characters of the word name, "SWAP":

```
83 'S'    87 'W'    65 'A'   80 'P'
```

And finally some padding to align on a 32-bit boundary:

```
0 '\000'    0 '\000'    0 '\000'
```

It would be nice if there was a way to format the word entry in a nicer manner.

If we do the following:

```
>>> x/1xw &name_SWAP
0x105cc:    0x000105bc
```

we note that `name_SWAP` is at `0x105cc`.

Let's use GDB's `printf` to display the word entry:

```
>>> printf "link: %#010x   name length: %i   name: %s\n", *(0x105cc), (char)*(0x105cc+4), (0x105cc+5)
link: 0x000105bc   name length: 4   name: SWAP
```

OK, that's not bad! We see the link, the name length, and name, all nicely displayed and labeled.

The downside here is that I have to use the explicit address in the call to `printf`:

```
printf "link: %#010x   name length: %i   name: %s\n", *(0x105cc), (char)*(0x105cc+4), (0x105cc+5)
```

Ideally, I'd just be able to say something like:

```
show_forth_word name_SWAP
```

and it'd display the above.

What's the best way to go about this? Is this doable with a [GDB user-defined command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html#Define)? Or is it something more appropriate for the [GDB Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python) interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, what's the best way to go about this?

It depends on whether GDB knows about the *type* of `name_SWAP`. If it does, the Python pretty-printer is the way to go.

If it doesn't, something as simple as user-defined command is likely easier. Assuming 32-bit mode:

```
define print_key
 set var $v = (char*)$arg0
 printf "link: %#010x   name length: %i   name: %s\n", *((char**)$v), *($v+4), ($v+5)
end
```

Comment: If I try `print_key name_SWAP` or `print_key &name_SWAP` I get the following: `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`.

Comment: @dharmatech Are you saying that `x/1xw &name_SWAP ` works, but `print_key &name_SWAP` doesn't? That's hard to believe.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/knxsiwb.png) of exactly that happening. :-)

Comment: @dharmatech I had a missing `$` in `set var ...`. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I just used `nm` , the good old Unix command.

Comment: The idea here is to show the actual data in the dictionary entry. `nm` as well as `objdump` shows the location of `name_SWAP`, but it doesn't show the fields in the dictionary entry (link, name length, name characters, etc.).

Comment: The "Forth" way is to create new Forth words yourself for this.

I am working on a [C to Forth (jonesforth) to C interface](https://github.com/udexon/5CSM/blob/master/Progress_20181203.md).

Do let me know if there is any overlap or opportunities for collaboration.